# Cannot use Kotlin backticked method names in androidTest - bad descriptor exception

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-testing

In my unit tests I use Kotlin's backticked methods for better readability, e.g.

```
@Test fun `Foo should return bar`()
```

It works nice and well for tests in `<module>/src/test` directory, but when I try to do the same in `<module>/src/androidTest` I get an exception:

```
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad descriptor: Lcom/packageName/MainActivityTest$Foo should return bar$1;
Error:Execution failed for task ':sample:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad descriptor: Lcom/packageName/MainActivityTest$Foo should return bar$1;
```

Is there some trick to make it work?

Comment: No, Android's dex format does not support spaces in method names.

Comment: You should submit an answer so that this question can be closed, @nhaarman. :-)

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - this is still not supported. It is the Android runtime, no solution from the developer perspective. Sadly you need to have 2 different naming conventions - one for unit tests and one for Android tests or just not use backticks in all the tests to be consistent.

Comment: Luckily there's **AndroidX Test** now, which omits the need to have two separate test directories :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Support for spaces in function names has been [added](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/ab5f4c17a86b8c808dba862db566f0ffa1146367) and is now available in API 30.

To use it, set `buildToolsVersion`, `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 30+  and run your tests on an Android 30+ device. If you want to use this in anything else than tests, you'll have to set `minSdkVersion` to 30+ as well.

Comment: It does work on 30+ but there are some tradeoffs. Android Studio 4.1.2 underlines as error those methods (it compiles fine). Also, it does not work when Orchestrator is enabled - it compiles but it hangs on instantiating tests. Nevertheless we're getting closer! :)

Comment: To fix the underlined error, add `@file:Suppress("IllegalIdentifier")` to the top of the file.

Comment: At Android Studio Chipmunk, the error goes away when you set minSdkVersion to 30 or higher. Ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208842981

Comment: Some recent changes in how Orchestrator runs tests might have fixed this issue. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Update: Backticks seem to work with Orchestrator. Documentation was updated https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests

Answer (score 18):

As @nhaarman mentioned, Android does not support backticked function names. From the [Kotlin Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html):

> In tests (and only in tests), it's acceptable to use method names with spaces enclosed in backticks. *(Note that such method names are currently not supported by the Android runtime.)* Underscores in method names are also allowed in test code.
>
> ```
> class MyTestCase {
>     @Test fun `ensure everything works`() { ... }
>     @Test fun ensureEverythingWorks_onAndroid() { ... }
> }
> ```

Comment: Why does Swift support it?

Comment: What does Swift have to do with this @IgorGanapolsky

Comment: @Dallas They are both very similar languages and compete for features.

Comment: Android and Swift compete for features? They're not even in the same ballpark of functionality. Android is a platform and Swift is a programming language. The whole issue here--as originally (but no longer) mentioned in the referenced docs--is that the DEX format didn't support various characters in function names. Android has since fixed that. Kotlin already supported it and was providing only a note for folks trying to do this with Android runtime tests.